# Resize do FitText só funciona depois de redimensionar página no jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, plugin

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com o jQuery Mobile e estou usando o plugin de *resize* de texto FitText. O plugin funciona bem, exceto que no jQuery Mobile, onde tenho várias *pages* em um único arquivo HTML, quando troco de página, o plugin de *resize* não seta os tamanhos que coloquei. Só funciona se eu começar a redimensionar a página.

Meu problema é [igual a esse que achei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754662/fittext-and-fastclick-wont-work-on-jquery-mobile-multi-page-layout) no Stack Overflow, mas o tópico está sem resposta.
Como resolver isso?

Comment: Pronto, dei uma recompensa pela resposta agora é só aguardar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754662/

Comment: Já que eu não uso minha conta gringa mesmo

Comment: Pode dar um link para a sua página ou colocar o seu codigo aqui?

Answer (score 1):

Isso parece ser um problema do plugin, que chama a função resize() antes do DOM estar pronto.
Aqui tem uma solução:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533945/fittext-will-only-work-when-window-is-resized

Answer (score 0):

Já experimentou móvel da jQuery construído em 'remissivo VCLIQUE' 300ms atraso característica de cometer. Usando isso, você pode omitir o uso FastClick. Porque Fastclick faz a mesma coisa, eliminando a demora 300ms. Você não está tendo nenhum problema com o jQuery Mobile e FitText. Então, você não vai sentir qualquer problema usando 'remissivo VCLIQUE' e FitText juntos. Você não terá que enfrentar muitos problemas. Aqui é um exemplo.

```
$("#element").bind('vclick', function(event) {
   decrementInput(this.id);event.preventDefault();
});
```